# trying to hit a logout link on click of a button but it shows failure

Tags: ios, swift3

On a button press action, I'm trying to invoke a logout request to a server. Here is the action code:

```
@IBAction func buttonpress(_ sender: UIButton) {

    Alamofire.request("https://securelogin.pu.ac.in/cgi-bin/login?cmd=logout").responseString { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        print(response.request)
        print(response.response)
        print(response.data)
        print(response.result)

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON \(JSON)")
        }
    }
}
```

But the response of this request always fails with the following error:

> [Request]: GET httpbin.org/get [Response]: nil [Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1742425e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=httpbin.org/get, NSErrorFailingURLKey=httpbin.org/get, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.} Optional(0 bytes) FAILURE

Can you please point me out what might cause this failure?

Comment: what error you are getting? For any post api's should pass some parameters. You are not passing anything here. Check your api documentation

Comment: You need to call web service with post method and with parameters like userid or access token

Comment: Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://securelogin.pu.ac.in/cgi-bin/login?cmd=logout/get",
                          parameters: nil, encoding: .URL).responseString(completionHandler: {
            (request: NSURLRequest, response: HTTPURLResponse?, responseBody: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

Comment: tried this too,, but it shows extra argument in call

Comment: [Request]: GET http://httpbin.org/get
[Response]: nil
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1742425e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://httpbin.org/get, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://httpbin.org/get, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.}
Optional(0 bytes)
FAILURE

Comment: this is what i am getting as error

Comment: ADD ATS in info.plist

Comment: Investigate your error log.